# How can I add a custom root node when serializing an object with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, custom-attributes

I have added a custom property to some of my objects like this:

```
[JsonCustomRoot("status")]
public class StatusDTO 
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute is very simple:

```
public class JsonCustomRoot :Attribute
{
    public string rootName { get; set; }

    public JsonCustomRoot(string rootName)
    {
        this.rootName = rootName;
    }
}
```

The default output from JSON.NET when serializing an instance of an object is this:

```
{"StatusId":70,"Name":"Closed","Created":"2012-12-12T11:50:56.6207193Z"}
```

Now the question is: **How can I add a root-node to the JSON with the value of the custom attribute like so**:

```
{status:{"StatusId":70,"Name":"Closed","Created":"2012-12-12T11:50:56.6207193Z"}}
```

I have found several articles mentioning the [IContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) interface, but I cannot grasp how to do it. My attempts include this unfinished piece of code:

```
protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
{
    JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

    var info = objectType.GetCustomAttributes()
                   .SingleOrDefault(t => (Type)t.TypeId==typeof(JsonCustomRoot));
    if (info != null)
    {
        var myAttribute = (JsonCustomRoot)info;
        // How can i add myAttribute.rootName to the root from here?
        // Maybe some other method should be overrided instead?
    }

    return contract;
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this, I don't want to wrap my responses on the controllers for each `GET`, I was looking for a way to do this as either a setting or a custom attribute on each model.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to do almost the same as yours but I'd be returning as an array even if only one object is returned e.g: `{status:[{"StatusId":70,"Name":"Closed","Created":"2012-12-12T11:50:56.6207193Z"}]}`. Also trying with `IContractResolver` and JSON.NET

Comment: I blogged about a solution specific to web api at http://www.emadibrahim.com/2014/04/09/emberjs-and-asp-net-web-api-and-json-serialization/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution specifically for Web API, which I am also using: [RootFormatter.cs](https://gist.github.com/4554127)

I wrote it based on [Creating a JSONP Formatter for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/02/Creating-a-JSONP-Formatter-for-ASPNET-Web-API).

Instead of using a custom attribute I am reusing Title field of `JsonObjectAttribute`. Here's a usage code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

[JsonObject(Title = "user")]
public class User
{
    public string mail { get; set; }
}
```

Then, add RootFormatter to your App_Start and register it as follows in `WebApiConfig`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new RootFormatter());
```

I was able to get a wrapped response similar to WCF's `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`:

```
{"user":{
  "mail": "foo@example.com"
}}
```

Comment: This is really cool! It would be epic though if it had a solution for collections.

Answer (score 13):

What if you use an anonymous object?

```
JSON.Serialize(new { status = targetObject});
```

Comment: I am using JSON.Net as a serializer on a .NET 4.0 WebAPI project, so I am trying to avoid writing custom code when returning data. I want it to be done for me when the attribute is applied.

Answer (score 5):

A very easy way of approaching this is to place the object inside another object. it maybe a over simplistic was of looking at it, but this works when working with collections, and singular objects.

```
  public class StatusDTO
    {
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

    public class statusJasonModel
    {
        public StatusDTO status { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you if you put the StatusDTO inside the statusJsonModel object and serialize it as Json. It should give you your desired answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar challenge in one of my project. Below is the step that I took in resolving the problem.

**1. My Entity class**

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }

    }
```

**2. Created another Class, which is defined in this form.**

```
    public class KindOfMedia
        {
            public KindOfMedia()
            {
                Product = new List<Product>();
            }
            public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
        }
```

**3. The Web API controller, that will return json**

```
            public HttpResponseMessage Products()
            {
                var kind = new KindOfMedia();
                kind.Products = new List<Product>();
                kind.Products.Add(new Product
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Title = "I am A Winner",
                    Album = "",
                    Artist = "Project Fame",
                    Genre = "Contemporal"                
                });
                kind.Products.Add(new Product
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Title = "Great Nation",
                    Album = "Oceans",
                    Artist = "Timi Dakolo",
                    Genre = "Gospel"
                });

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, kind);
            }
```

**4. Add this line of code to my WebApi Config file in App_Start folder**

```
     var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
                json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

please note that **Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None**, will not preserve reference of the serialize type

The resulting Json is

```
{
  "Musics": [
    {
      "Id": "bf9faeee-7c39-4c33-a0ea-f60333604061",
      "Title": "I am A Winner",
      "Album": "",
      "Artist": "Project Fame",
      "Genre": "Contemporal"
    },
    {
      "Id": "243edd32-7ba2-4ac4-8ab9-bba6399cb0a6",
      "Title": "Great Nation",
      "Album": "Oceans",
      "Artist": "Timi Dakolo",
      "Genre": "Gospel"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where does it get the Musics root object from?