# WebAPI custom root

Tags: vb.net, ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I've been searching far and wide for an answer, but every time I have come to a point where I'm hitting my head against a brick wall.

I need to have my data from WebApi served in a manner so that Ember-data can use them.

The following link seems to have the right answer:
[How can I add a custom root node when serializing an object with JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839426/how-can-i-add-a-custom-root-node-when-serializing-an-object-with-json-net)

But this part isn't allowed in VisualBasic.Net

```
' GET api/<controller>
<JsonObject(Title:="users")> _
Public Function GetValues() As List(Of myclassname)
```

> **The following error is returned**
>   Attribute 'JsonObjectAttribute' cannot be applied to 'GetValues' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

I suspect this to be something trivial... hoping, rather. :-)

Comment: If I were god, I would judge you for using VB.Net in 2014

Comment: If you'd like to help me convert a 120,000 lines big project to C# ... Be my guest!

Comment: Everything has a price :)