# Json.Net serialize/deserialize Class Name attribute C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin.forms, simple.odata.client

Sorry for the (maybe) trivial  question but, I'm trying to consume a web service where the entities and my data model classes are  named different.

I want to keep my model .Net Class name and use a Json Attribute name to map, serializer/deserializer, with the corresponding web service entity.
For example:

Web Service Entity:

"People"

My Model Class:

"Employee"

What I've already do:

```
[JsonObject(Title="People")]
public class Employee 
{

   [JsonProperty("DifferentPropertyName")]
   string propertyName1 { get; set; }
}
```

But the json serializer/Deserializer continues to use the .Net class name  and I need to set the jsonObject Title.

There is a way to achieve it?

**EDIT**

*I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app, using [Simple.OData.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client/) to consume an OData Service*

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839426/how-can-i-add-a-custom-root-node-when-serializing-an-object-with-json-net

Comment: Maybe this can help:
`[JsonProperty(Title="People")] 
public string propertyName1{get; set;}`

Comment: Please show serialization/deserialization code that is doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks... The problem is not with the properties but with the class name. As I'm using the simple.odata.client nuget package I'm trying to deserialize a resource entity that is named "People" into a .net class (model) named  "Employee". At this point the simple.odata.client looks for a service resource (entity)  named "Employee" that can't be found.

Comment: Have you tried serializing to JSON string first then deserializing that string into you Employee class? Might not be good for performance but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) may be your solution.

```
public class RichFilter
{
   public Trolo item { get; set; }
}
[DataContract(Name = "item")]
public class Trolo 
{ 
   public string connector { get; set; } 
}
```

If you serialize a RichFilter object, here is the output :

```
{"item":{"connector":"AND"}}
```

Comment: When using the `DataContractAttribute` you **must** also specify the `DataMemberAttribute` on [properties you want to serialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm).

Comment: Since I was using Simple.OData.Client, that is not able to recognize the DataContract attribute, I had to pass the name of my remote element explicitly. I, anyway, used a custom attribute like "ClassName" with a property that returns the name of the class but this is too much work for its purpose.